# Explicitely returning escaped JSON response vs just returning array in Laravel/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

If I compare the [5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#json-responses) and [5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#creating-responses) docs of Laravel, the 5.3 docs seem to encourage just returning an array with data which will automatically be turned into a JSON response (with the content-type **"application/json"**). I noticed that returning an array from the controller, will return unescaped JSON.

```
return ['country_id' => $countryId, 'iso2' => 'EG', 'iso3' => 'EGY', 'country_name' => $countryName, 'name' => 'EGYPT', 'active' => 1, 'published' => 1];
```

returns

```
[{"country_id":63,"iso2":"EG","iso3":"EGY","country_name":"Egypt","name":"EGYPT","active":1,"published":1}]
```

but explicitly converting a PHP array to a JSON string with **json_encode()** and returning that as a response, returns escaped JSON.

```
return response()->json(json_encode(['country_id' => $countryId, 'iso2' => 'EG', 'iso3' => 'EGY', 'country_name' => $countryName, 'name' => 'EGYPT', 'active' => 1, 'published' => 1]));
```

returns

```
[{\"country_id\":63,\"iso2\":\"EG\",\"iso3\":\"EGY\",\"country_name\":\"Egypt\",\"name\":\"EGYPT\",\"active\":1,\"published\":1}]
```

Is there any reason to use the more verbose way of returning (i'm not using eval on the client side, only JSON.parse() which converts the unescaped and escaped JSON to the same javascript object)?

Comment: I don't really know laravel much, but to me it seems that escape shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points:

1. According the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#creating-responses

> The framework will automatically convert the array into a JSON response

like:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return [1, 2, 3];
});
```

2. And according to https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#json-responses

> The json method will automatically set the Content-Type header to application/json, as well as convert the given array into JSON using the json_encode PHP function

like:

```
return response()->json([
   'name' => 'Abigail',
       'state' => 'CA'
]);
```

You're right in both, but you're obtaining escaped code because you're using `json_encode()` twice, one  because of the `response()->json()` that uses internally that function according the docs, and the other explicitly in your code within that function: `response()->json(json_encode(...))`, remove the inner `json_encode` to work normally.

I've tested the both styles and the headers received are the same, so I consider the use of explicit `response()->json()` vs just returning an array as a matter of preference as long as you work with a version that implements that feature. It seems that 5.2 and below doesn't.